# Pipeline for Create/Update Segmented List in Sitecore 9.0 EXM

Tags: exm

What I am doing

- Creating a segmented list form an existing contact list
- On create and update of the segmented List I need to write some custom logic for display name and security
- I need to tap into the `Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch.Pipelines` to call my own custom code

I am trying to use the pipeline as shown below but the it is not working.
Am I missing/using the wrong pipeline?

```
<listManagement.CreateList>
    <processor
        type="XXX.XXX.Web.Helper.AccessPermissions, XXX.XXX.Web"
        patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch.Pipelines.CreateList.CreateContactList, Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch']" resolve="true">
    </processor>
  </listManagement.CreateList>
  <listManagement.UpdateList>
    <processor
        type="XXX.XXX.Web.Helper.AccessPermissions, XXX.XXX.Web"
        patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch.Pipelines.UpdateList.UpdateContactList, Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch']" resolve="true">
    </processor>
  </listManagement.UpdateList>
</pipelines>
```

Sitecore version : 9.0 Update 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened up a sitecore support ticket and turns out there is no easy way to customize the name and security setting.

- When you create a segmented list from the existing list and "save" the list, the background js code send out request to the "segmentedListController" (sitecore.ListManagement.Services.dll).
- This controller will then ask Sitecore to create the list item based on the entity data.
- The name of the list is "hard coded" with the method below:
  ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName(FormattableString.Invariant($"{entity.Name}-{guid}")), ContextCulture, entity.Name, DateUtil.ToUniversalTime(DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime(entity.Created, DateTime.UtcNow)), entity.CreatedBy ?? Context.User.Name)

Also

```
<listManagement.CreateList>
<processor
    type="XXX.XXX.Web.Helper.AccessPermissions, XXX.XXX.Web"
    patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch.Pipelines.CreateList.CreateContactList, Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch']" resolve="true">
</processor>
```

Older Sitecore version, eg: Sitecore 8.1, has this assembly and pipeline. 
This processor is called when you create contact list from csv file. 
So creating segmented list from List manager won't trigger this pipeline.